# AngularJS: How to set $scope.var in a view only after the $scope.var is set?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a view in my angular that looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range(newsList.length)" ng-class="{active: n == paging}" ng-click="setPage()">
                    <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                </li>
```

Now the problem is in the `newsList`, that scope is set only after an `$http` request is send and response is received. Like this:

```
$http.get('news/listings/' + ($scope.currentPage*$scope.itemsPerPage) + '/' + (($scope.currentPage+1)*$scope.itemsPerPage)).success (response) ->
    $scope.newsList = response
```

The real problem is that, the view renders first BEFORE the `$scope.newsList` is set, the variable is `undefined` in the view. How to tell the view that I want to render those `li` only after `$scope.newsList` is set?

By the way, I call that `$http` request in the controller where the view was made.

**EDIT**
In my controller, this is what happens if i output the $scope.newsList value

```
$http.get('news/listings/' + ($scope.currentPage*$scope.itemsPerPage) + '/' + (($scope.currentPage+1)*$scope.itemsPerPage)).success (response) ->
        $scope.newsList = response
        alert $scope.newsList //returns object, which I want

alert $scope.newsList //undefined
```

**edit again**

Solved my problem, but raised another question (along with solution for this question): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398692/angularjs-ng-repeat-how-to-orderby-for-object-of-objects)

Comment: Simply show them with: `ng-show="newsList"` , may be?

Comment: updated my code to `<li ng-show="newsList" ng-repeat="n in range(newsList.length)" ng-class="{active: n == paging}" ng-click="setPage()">
      <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
     </li>`, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Either initialise `$scope.newsList` with empty array:

```js
$scope.newList = [];
$http.get(...
```

or use `ngIf` in your view:

```html
<ul ng-if="newsList.length">
  <li 
    ng-repeat="n in range(newsList.length)" 
    ng-class="{active: n == paging}" 
    ng-click="setPage()"
  >
    <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$resource` service has `isArray` configuration that makes it return an empty array before data is fetched. Can you try this option? I can't find any documentation at the moment.

```
$http.get(url, {isArray : true }).success(someCallback);
```