# AngularJS ng-repeat how to orderBy for object of objects?

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have a response from the server like this:

```
0: {
    0: {
        category: "value1",
        date: "date",
        id: 100,
        title: "MyTitle",
        edituser: "user1",
    }
    hashKey: "02G",
    _proto:{
        //not important,
    }
},
1: {
    1: {
        category: "value2",
        date: "date",
        id: 101,
        title: "MyTitle2",
        edituser: "user2",
    }
    hashKey: "02H",
    _proto:{
        //not important,
    }
},
```

which need to be shown in a list like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="news in newsList[currentPage] | orderObjectBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
        <td>{{news[$index].id}}</td>
        <td>{{news[$index].title}}</td>
        <td>{{news[$index].category}}</td>
        <td>{{news[$index].edituser}}</td>
        <td>{{news[$index].date}}</td>
    </tr>
```

It shows just fine, but the ordering is not fine. Using normal `orderBy` won't do it, so I created a custom filter like this (in coffeescript):

```
app.filter "orderObjectBy", ->
(items, field, reverse) ->
    filtered = []
    angular.forEach items, (item) ->
        filtered.push item

    filtered.sort (a, b) ->
        a[field] > b[field]

    filtered.reverse()  if reverse
    filtered
```

but still it won't sort, is there any solution to sort that kind of response object in angular?

Comment: Where is `sortingOrder` in the json?

Comment: `sortingOrder` is the predicate for order, like 'title', I set it as `$scope.sortingOrder`

Comment: like this `$scope.sortingOrder = 'category'`

Comment: I do something like this: `<tr ng-repeat="news in newsList[currentPage] | orderObjectBy:'category':reverse">`, won't work either, even without `reverse` also won't work

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @ayushnarula: i don't, i just change my code design in the end

Answer (score 1):

Mistake is in the compare function. It should return number. 
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

This works:

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', () ->
    (items, field, reverse) ->
        filtered = []

        for key, item of items
            filtered.push(item)

        filtered.sort( (a, b) ->
            if a[field] > b[field]
                return 1 
            else 
                return -1
    )

        if (reverse) 
            filtered.reverse()

        return filtered

);
```